# Use File and Directory key for VBS custom action InstallShield

Tags: vbscript, installshield

I would like to confirm this method. When creating EXE custom action in InstallShield you can call directory of your project by using [DIRKey] and a file using [#FILEKey]. Now I'm trying to do same thing to VBS custom action. I set my custom action in differed in system context but unfortunately this is not working. May I know if there's a way to do same mechanics in VBS custom action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. VBScript / JScript custom actions are fragile.  I'd suggest [reading up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx) on this and choosing InstallScript, C++ or C#/DTF instead.
2. Translating [dirprop] [#filekey] to a full path requires an MSI session handle that has full access.  Deferred custom actions lack this.  To overcome this you must have an immediatecustom action make the evaluation and then pass that as CustomActionData to the deferred custom action.
3. EXE custom actions get around this because the custom action implicitly gets called twice.  Once to schedule the operation (immediate)  and in this case the translation is automatic and then once in deferred where it actually gets executed.
4. There are a number of things that [can go wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2007/10/24/exe-custom-actions-are-bad.aspx) when calling an EXE.  This can be mitigated (even in InstallShield) by using the [WiX QuietExecCA](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) either by "stealing" the DLL  or by encapsulating it in a merge module project and consuming that in InstallShield.
5. Realize that custom actions shouldn't reinvent the wheel.  I don't know what your EXE is but if there's any way of breaking this down into pieces that can be expressed by Windows Installer your complexity and risk will greatly decrease.
6. Keep in mind that custom actions that change the machine configuration should be authored to support rollback.  This means more custom actions.